# Qual evento mostra se o teclado do android está ou não ativo?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-fragment

Existe algum evento ou método que mostra se o teclado está ativo na tela do android, pois preciso fazer essa verificação numa Fragment.

Comment: Voce quer dizer se o teclado está sendo mostrado para o usuário?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Achei esse 2 códigoS no SOEN

Modo 1

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
        writeToLog("Software Keyboard was shown");
    } else {
        writeToLog("Software Keyboard was not shown");
    }
```

Modo 2

```
contentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {

    Rect r = new Rect();
    contentView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
    int screenHeight = contentView.getRootView().getHeight();

    // r.bottom is the position above soft keypad or device button.
    // if keypad is shown, the r.bottom is smaller than that before.
    int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

    Log.d(TAG, "keypadHeight = " + keypadHeight);

    if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) { // 0.15 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
        // keyboard is opened
    }
    else {
        // keyboard is closed
    }
}
});
```

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device

Comment: Certo, mas como eu faço um loop pra ficar fazendo essa verificação?